# Read timed out error - javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException

Tags: java, spring, soap, weblogic, jax-ws

I'm trying to debug a critical issue where a JSP application is seeing request timeouts when making call to a remote web service.

I should clarify the timeout doesn't happen at all time, for smaller queries the web service does return response.

I have tried increasing the timeout value in WebLogic server > Protocols > HTTP > Post timeout and Duration. I have also tried to set JAX-WS properties in my spring.xml as follows:

```
<util:map id="jaxwsCustomProperties">  
    <entry key="com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout">  
        <value type="java.lang.Integer">650000</value>  
    </entry>  
    <entry key="com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout">  
        <value type="java.lang.Integer">650000</value>  
    </entry>  
</util:map>
```

Console output:

```
org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsSoapFaultException: Request timeout.
Read timed out; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Request timeout.
Read timed out
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:395)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:379)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy72.getDeviceList(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.msr.web.actionbean.DeviceListProcessor.getDeviceList(DeviceListProcessor.java:223)
    at com.company.msr.web.actionbean.MsrMainActionBean.listToJson(MsrMainActionBean.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper$6.intercept(DispatcherHelper.java:467)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:158)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.intercept(BeforeAfterMethodInterceptor.java:113)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.proceed(ExecutionContext.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.ExecutionContext.wrap(ExecutionContext.java:74)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherHelper.invokeEventHandler(DispatcherHelper.java:465)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.invokeEventHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:278)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.doFilter(StripesFilter.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.company.msr.web.actionbean.UserAccessFilter.doFilter(UserAccessFilter.java:53)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at com.company.msr.web.actionbean.filter.AjaxFilter.doFilter(AjaxFilter.java:29)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Request timeout.
Read timed out
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at $Proxy108.getDeviceList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.doInvoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:392)
```

I have been unsuccessful with all attempts. Any ideas on how to resolve this are deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which JRE / JAX-WS implementation are you using?

Comment: Did you check with the server side team? One time I face similar issue to access external server WSDL file. Some time it was showing and some times not. After checking with server team they confirm that they were deploying their application in two different servers and one of them was down. Some how my requests was coming to down one and some times goes to the up one. I do not know if this will help you but engaging the server side may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following for your webserver (Server Start tab or put it into your startWebLogic.sh script):

Specifies, in seconds, how long a client application that is attempting to invoke a Web service waits to make a connection. After the specified time elapses, if a connection hasn't been made, the attempt times out.

```
-Dweblogic.http.client.defaultConnectTimeout=650000
```

Specifies, in seconds, how long a client application waits for a response from a Web service it is invoking. After the specified time elapses, if a response hasn't arrived, the client times out.

```
-Dweblogic.http.client.defaultReadTimeout=650000
```

References here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13760/client.htm#i227120

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29597_01/fusionapps.1111/e14496/compliance.htm

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this but no luck. Also tried setting `-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=650000` `-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=650000` `-Dweblogic.wsee.transport.read.timeout=650000`, none of them seem to resolve timeout.